# Is it possible to open a file directly from S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto

I use Amazon S3 for storage for my resources, but sometimes I find its necessary to open a file that's stored on S3, in order to do some operations on it.

Is it at all possible (and advisable) to open the files directly from S3, or should I just stick to using a temporary "scratch" folder?

Right now I am using the [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto) extensions for interfacing with Amazon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to open a file on S3, you can only read them or add/replace them over the network.

There is an open source command line tool called [s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon) which emulates mounting an s3 bucket as a user space file system. With it mounted like this you can use any commands that you would use on ordinary files in your file system to open read and write to a file, but behind the scenes it is doing some local caching for all your writes and then uploading the file when you close the handle.